# Actions on Google - Browsing carousel changed behavior?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

We've been the Browsing Carousel object in our action and been happy with it. We've notice that Google have changed the appearance of the object and it now looks like a list and not a carousel. Has anyone else noticed it? Is there any way around it to make it look like a carousel again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That's the thing I have also noticed in new Google Assistant design and I don't see any updates in the documentation or in Dialogflow console.

So there is nothing available until now to get it back to carousel like the one in the previous version. So have to wait for some updates from Google.

Comment: Thanks, Satish. This is a very miserable move by them :(